# Microsoft graph api calendarview delta issues

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am currently using the Microsoft graph API to get `events` from Outlook, but I would like to change to the `calendarView` endpoint instead. However, I am facing a number of challenges when using `delta` links on other users calendars with delegated access.

My first call to the `delta` endpoint works as intended, but when I try to use the link in `@odata.nextLink` for next delta data I get an permission error - and can't see what should cause this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-12-06T18:03:31",
            "request-id": "961ca04c-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "client-request-id": "2dc7f5ea-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    }
}
```

Delta querying works fine when done on the `events` endpoint so I am a bit lost in what to check for?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are facing challenges while using delta links on other users calendars with delegated access. For accessing other user data ,which required application permission , where as delegated permission required user to signIn , please check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview) for more info regarding delegated permission vs application permission .

Could you please try adding **Calendars.Read** application permission instead of delegated permission - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: At the moment I need to use delegated access only, however, then I don't understand why this currently works on the 'events' with delegate permission but not 'calendarView' endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and found a partial answer at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587998/deltatoken-for-calendar-events-requiring-elevated.html

I asked my Active Directory admin to give manage access for the account associated with my bearer token, and the delta events are now working. That is, `myuser@example.com` now has manage permissions for `shared-calendar-user@example.com`. This isn't ideal, but it's acceptable for my use case.